# How to use Arrays in Hapi swaggered-ui on GET request so it would work?

Tags: swagger-ui, hapi.js, swagger-2.0, joi

Usecase: Hapi.js + hapi-swaggered + hapi-swaggered-ui.

Swaggered UI submits an array. It passes comma separated String instead of Array. How to I make it pass correct parameters, should I change validation type on Joi? 
I am using:

```
query: Joi.object({ categories : Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).label('Categories') })
```

Query it does: `?categories=firstCategory%2CsecondCategory`

Query it should do: `?categories=firstCategory&categories=secondCategory`

Comment: I'm confused, can you post an example query string?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: :D I didn't mean a generic query string, I meant, one that you're expecting to match your Joi schema.

Comment: ?categories=firstCategory&categories=secondCategory

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of sending array in query param. And joi will not recognize it. Send it as `payload`. If you want to send it in query param, you will have to convert the query params into array and then validate.